# How to train a doc2vec model in tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow.js, doc2vec

I want to create an app for serving nlp problems. I need to deploy doc2vec model on frontend  for which i am looking for tensorflow.js framework. My need is to train a doc2vec model in tensorflow.js for deploying it on the browser.
Is it possible to train a doc2vec model in tensorflow.js?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you can train a doc2vec model in Python as a Keras/TensorFlow model, you will be able to convert it to a tensorflow.js model.

Try this tutorial to get the model trained:
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html

Comment: This is just for deploying the model in the browser. Can you train the model in the browser?